# Gateway Timeout on Group Drive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I do a simple get on `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/ee7ca7f8-f838-4caf-ab9b-84c133ccd003/drive` for a new group and then I get a `504 Gateway Timeout` with this body:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "f3edd69f-6747-49fb-b41c-925ef2381bad",
      "date": "2017-07-28T20:12:58"
    }
  }
}
```

Why?

Comment: Could you provide some additional detail about this Group? What do you get when you request `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/ee7ca7f8-f838-4caf-ab9b-84c133ccd003`

Comment: The drive call starting working after I had accessed the document library through the UI/or I had waited for some time. I think it would make sense to return something else than 504 if the drive entry not ready yet.

Comment: Ah, yes. This is a known issue. Until a drive is opened via the UI it isn't fully provisioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until a drive is opened via the UI it isn't fully provisioned.